# $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| dx < \infty \implies \int^{\infty}_{n} |f(x)| dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Suppose that $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| dx < \infty$.

> Can we say that $\int^{\infty}_{n} |f(x)| dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ If yes, how to justify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Let $f_n=1_{[n;\infty)}f$.

Then $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions dominated by $f$.

The pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ is $0$ for every $x$ and thus, by the dominated convergence theorem

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^\infty|f(x)|dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{R} |f_n(x)|dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{R} |f_n(x)-0(x)|dx=0$.

QED.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

$$\int_n^\infty \lvert f\rvert\,dx=\int_{\Bbb R} 1_{[n,\infty)}\lvert f\rvert\,dx$$

Since $1_{[n.\infty)}\lvert f\rvert\le\lvert f\rvert$ and $1_{[n,\infty)}\lvert f\rvert\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0\ $ pointwise, you can use [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: You beat me to it :p

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$ \int^{\infty}_0|f(x)|dx\le\int_{-\infty}^0|f(x)|dx+\int^{\infty}_0|f(x)|dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|dx<\infty$$
and hence for $\forall \varepsilon>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for $\forall m, n\ge N$ ($m>n$),
$$ \int_n^m|f(x)|dx<\varepsilon$$
Letting $m\to\infty$ gives
$$ \int_n^\infty|f(x)|dx\le\varepsilon$$
namely
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^\infty|f(x)|dx=0.$$

Comment: Why $\int_{n}^{m} |f| <\epsilon ?$

Comment: @abcd, by the Cauchy theorem.

Comment: Thanks: But which [Cauchy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_theorem)?

Comment: @abcd, see http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/m4342f10/improper_integrals.pdf.